# opening an .exe after using Mingw

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I followed the instructions in this video:([See Docs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NKF8zt5Mmg&list=PLCD69CF11168015F4&index=4))

What happened is that I created a very basic program in C, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hey Buddy!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `Mingw` and an `.exe` file was created. Here the problem begins...

When simply opening the file in windows, a `cmd` window that says "Hey Buddy!" opens and closes immediately.

When trying to run the `.exe` file using the command line, the same thing happens, but the command line window then becomes stuck and it is impossible to close it - only shutting off the computer can do it.

Your help would be very appreciated, and I am sorry if I am doing something dumb and not realizing it:)

Comment: Simply type `exit` and press enter after program execution is over, at command prompt

Comment: Before return you can write getch() to stop it from closing immediately ..

Comment: push(click) × BUTTON.

Comment: Of course I tried to click the x button, and also used the task manager. It's as if something caused the window to get stuck. I can't type anything in there either, after executing the .exe from the command prompt - it doesn't start a new line.

Comment: With recent versions of Windows, click the X button and wait a few seconds and you'll be given a choice to kill the frozen application. No need to turn off the computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is fine. The `main` declaration is wrong. It should be

```
int main(void)
```

but the declaration in your question won't cause any problems. I'm just telling you this to set you off on the right path.

Of course when you double click on the executable, then a new console window appears and immediately disappears. The program prints a single line of text and returns immediately. That behaviour is as expected.

The problem with the console window that cannot be closed is not down to an error in your code, at least the code that is shown in the question cannot explain that. That is presumably an environmental problem with your machine and/or compiler installation. Or perhaps you just have not yet worked out how to close a console window.